# How can I get return value ( string ) from called Python by BatchFile

Tags: python, batch-file

I need to have some help.

I used python33 on Windows OS.

I want result it.

Call Python in Batch File.
( `python Testing.py %arg1% %arg2%` )

python is do return string value.
( `return('END') or exit('END')` )

and I want set BatchFile Variable 
( `SET returnValue = python Testing.py %arg1% %arg2%`  )

and Use Variable `%returnValue%`

I tried search key word. 
'python return value to batch file'

I found this hint.
( Python ) sys.exit(number)
So Called %ErrorLevel% in BatchFile.

But this Sample can integer. don't apply string.

Of course, Python can make string in file. and Batch File can Load File .

or Also Environment Variable can.

But I want different method.

I want just Python do Return value and How use the Return Value in Batch File .

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  stackoverflow isn't a code-writing service, you need to show what you have already tried and explain how what it does is different from what you want to do.

Comment: @TheBlackCat Thank you. I'm sorry this problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As far I have understood your question. You would like to execute a python script from a batch file and then would like to save the output of the python script to a variable in the batch file.

Here is my way (there could be a better way to do this). I am simply executing the python script `test2.py` from my batch file and then I save the output of the python script to a temporary file called as `Output` later I read this file to a batch file variable named as `MYVAR` and then I am deleting the temp file `Output`.

The **batch code** is provided below:

```
@ECHO OFF
test2.py > Output
SET /p MYVAR=<Output
ECHO %MYVAR%
PAUSE
DEL Output
```

The python file `test2.py` contains the following code:

```
print "Python"
```

The batch file & the python file are in the same directory!

**Output**:

Upon executing the batch file you shall see this in the console:

```
Python
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Wow.. It so Very Simple.

Comment: As far I have understood this code :D
this Code > Output 
saved first print

so i removed otiose my comment.
Thank you for answer.
I owe you, pss.

Comment: You are welcome. Happy coding :)

Comment: but this ">Outbut" saved only the first print. I need it to save the last print/ or last value result, how can I do it?

Comment: @ZuiZui From your first Python script, create a temporary text file and write your last print's string into that text file. And then simply access that text file to retrieve the string.