# Passing variable number of arguments to batch file from a python file

Tags: python, windows, variables, batch-file, arguments

I have a sample.bat file that has variable number of parameters. These parameters are coming from a python file:

```
# sample.py

p = Popen(['sample.bat', module_name_vista,
           memory_type_vista, linker_name_vista])

errors = p.communicate()
p.wait()
```

I want to know is there a way to pass variable number of arguments when invoking sample.bat file?

The number of parameters will vary depending on how user wants to use the batch file.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32560443/2382792

Answer (score 1):

How about making the list dynamically and then passing it to `Popen`.

```
process_params_list = ['sample.bat']

for param in all_params:
  #condition for param to be added or not
  #or other processing on param
  process_params_list.append(param)

p = Popen(process_params_list)
```